# Why does it say "Trying to reference a deleted function"?

Tags: c++, stl

I'm trying to customize an iterator, however, inserting an element from VECTOR into set on the last line prompts "Trying to reference a deleted function"? Why is this?I think it might be an inline function, but I don't know what to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename Container>
class asso_insert_iterator : public std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, typename Container::value_type> {
protected:
    Container& container;

public:
    explicit asso_insert_iterator(Container& c) : container(c){};

    asso_insert_iterator<Container>& operator=(const typename Container::value_type& value)
    {
        container.insert(value);
        return *this;
    }

    asso_insert_iterator<Container>& operator*()
    {
        return *this;
    }

    asso_insert_iterator<Container>& operator++()
    {
        return *this;
    }

    asso_insert_iterator<Container>& operator++(int)
    {
        return *this;
    }
};

template <typename Container>
inline asso_insert_iterator<Container> asso_inserter(Container& c)
{
    return asso_insert_iterator<Container>(c);
}

int main()
{
    std::unordered_set<int> coll;
    asso_insert_iterator<decltype(coll)> iter(coll);
    *iter = 1;
    iter++;
    *iter = 2;
    std::copy(coll.begin(), coll.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::vector<int> val = { 33, 67, -4, 13, 5, 2 };
    std::copy(val.begin(), val.end(), asso_inserter(coll));
}
```

Comment: Please post the complete error message

Comment: Works on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/v191TdxPx)

Comment: You forgot to `#include <iterator>`, but then it seems to work.

Comment: After adding the required `#include <iterator>`, MSVC does give the "attempting to reference a deleted function" error, which I solved by supplying a dummy normal assignment operator to `asso_insert_iterator`. Not sure what's the proper way to implementing it due to `Container& container` member.

Comment: Whatever the issue is, whether it is a compiler bug, or legitimate bug (different compilers give differing results), it's being caused by the reference member `Container& container`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie *Iterator* requires *CopyAssignable*, so it's a straight up bug

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `asso_insert_iterator` is not an [*Iterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Iterator), because it is not [*CopyAssignable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyAssignable).

The simplest fix is to have a pointer member rather than a reference member.

```
template <typename Container>
class asso_insert_iterator : public std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, typename Container::value_type> {
protected:
    Container* container;

public:
    explicit asso_insert_iterator(Container& c) : container(std::addressof(c)){};

    asso_insert_iterator<Container>& operator=(const typename Container::value_type& value)
    {
        container->insert(value);
        return *this;
    }

    asso_insert_iterator<Container>& operator*()
    {
        return *this;
    }

    asso_insert_iterator<Container>& operator++()
    {
        return *this;
    }

    asso_insert_iterator<Container>& operator++(int)
    {
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me fix this, but I still don't understand why this class is not copyassignable? My class inherits the iterator class publicly, which should be an iterator.

Comment: @BITCOIN100K `std::iterator` isn't an *Iterator*, it's a template that provides a bunch of type aliases that *Iterator* requires. Your class isn't copy assignable because of the reference member. The compiler generated copy assignment operator is deleted, because you can't rebind a reference. `std::iterator` was deprecated in C++17 partly because of this confusion.